# Can I connect a SATA3 SSD to an ASATA port?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

Due to the structure of the computer case, I can't connect the hard drive and SSD to the SATA3 ports. I connected them to ASATA.

How this will affect the processor and the system as a whole, or there is no difference. On the forums, opinions are divided and nothing is clear. I'm talking about SSD M.2 I know, I don't have it in my system.

Comment: The ASATA ports your reference are actually SATA ports.  The manual for your motherboard will describe their relationship to your M.2 NVMe slot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect SATA3 drives to ASATA ports but with a caveat.

ASATA stands for APU SATA.  They're driven by a separate AMD Accelerated Processing Unit (APU).  An APU may have have support for two USB 3.0 ports, two SATA 6 Gbit/s ports, as well as the xHCI 1.0 and SD/SDIO 3.0 protocols for SD-card support.

The APU for ASATA will only work IF there's nothing plugged into something that shares the APU PCIe lanes, typically the primary M.2 connector.  That's the caveat.  As @Ramhound's comment states, the motherboard manual should have a matrix showing which connections will automatically disable ASATA ports.